# Code hiding and line numbers IDLE

Tags: python, python-idle

Is there any way to enable code hiding (hides the details of a class or a function just shows the definition) and line numbers in IDLE ?

Comment: A line number sidebar for IDLE editor windows was just added and will be in future releases.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think so.  [It was discussed briefly on the mailing lists](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/idle-dev/2007-February/002554.html), but I don't believe anything's come out of it since.

If you're interested in code folding, look into slightly more powerful editors - Geany (GTK) and Sublime Text both support code folding.

Answer (score 0):

A code/line folding feature was asked before in that [Python Issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue37882). It was closed and rejected but with good reasons.

If you know this features of IDLE you maybe do not need code folding anymore.

1. **Module Browser**:
   To get an outline view of a file's classes and functions, use *File => Module Browser* (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).
2. **Code Context**:
   To get a dynamic view of nested compound statement headers with *Options => Code Context*.